# Converting 10011.010 to binary

Tags: binary

So I can do the non fractional part of the conversion (10011 is 19) but I have no idea how to convert .010. I can't find many resources or step by step guides for this either. Am I still using position and powers of 2?

Comment: You have an algorithm for this, keep multiplying with 2, and sieve out integer part.

Comment: [look at this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987176/how-do-you-convert-a-fraction-to-binary) and [this page](http://cs.furman.edu/digitaldomain/more/ch6/dec_frac_to_bin.htm) to get an idea. By the way $10011.010_2 = 19.25_{10}$

Comment: Are you converting **to** or **from** binary? The question is somewhat confusing.

Comment: To decimal, apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in base ten where the first decimal corresponds to $10^{-1}$, the second to $10^{-2}$.

In base two $0.abc...$ correspond to $a2^{-1} + b2^{-2} + c2^{-3}...$ where $a,b,c\in \{0,1\}$ are the bits.

Therefore 0.010 is $0 \cdot 2^{-1} + 1\cdot 2^{-2} + 0 \cdot 2^{-3} = 1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just multiply this fraction with 2 few times.

[You can see this link for more help.](http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://cs.furman.edu/digitaldomain/more/ch6/dec_frac_to_bin.htm&grqid=sPh2knWg&hl=en-IN)